# Benchmarking with googletest?

Tags: c++, benchmarking, googletest

### Background (skip to Question below if not interested)

I have a simulator that runs through three states:

1. Single threaded startup (I/O ok)
2. Multi-threaded in-memory CPU-bound simulation stage **(I/O not ok)**
3. Post-simulation, post-join single threaded stage (I/O ok)

**What the heck!**  During standard testing, CPU usage dropped from **100% down to 20%**, and the total run took about **30 times longer than normal (130secs vs 4.2secs).**

When `Callgrind` revealed nothing suspicious, my head buzzed as I was on the precipice of rolling back to the last commit, losing all bug-fixes.

Discouraged, I walked into the server room during a run and noticed nasty grinding sounds, verified later to be caused by writes to Mysql sockets in [/proc/PID/fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181662/disk-io-profiler-for-a-c-application-on-linux)!!!  It turned out that Mysql code, several layers deep in Stage 2., was causing problems.

**Lessons Learned**

1. Accidental I/O can be lethal to a real-time application
2. Unit testing is not enough:  I need benchmarking, too

**Fix**  I will introduce thread-local-storage IOSentinels and asserts() on ReadAllowed() and WriteAllowed() to ensure that Stage 2 threads will never do any IO.

### Question

**Anyone have any luck with attaching/writing a benchmarking framework with googletest?**

Unfortunately, all my googletests passed this time.  Had I stepped away for a bit and come back without noticing the run-time, this would have been a disastrous commit, and possibly much harder to fix.

I would like googletest to fail if a run takes >2 or 3 times the last runtime: this last part is tricky because for very quick runs, system state can cause something to take twice as long but still be ok.  But for a long simulation run/test, I don't expect runtimes to change by a great deal (>50% would be unusual).

I am open to suggestions here, but it would be nice to have a low-maintenance check that would work with automated testing so it will be obvious if the system suddenly got slow, even if all the outputs appear to be ok.

Answer (score 5):

I do this in v1.5.0:

```
BENCHMARK(SomeBenchmark);
BENCHMARK(AnotherBenchmark);

TEST(MyTest, Benchmarks)
{
    ::benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
}
```

That is, I just call RunSpecifiedBenchmarks directly in one of the gtest tests.

Answer (score 4):

Google Test framework proposes by default a measure of elapsed time. It is commanded by an environment variable, `GTEST_PRINT_TIME`. This variable defaults to `1`.

So, why not monitor elapsed time using this feature of Google Test platform?

Here is a [word on elapsed time variable in Google Test](http://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#suppressing-the-elapsed-time):

> By default, googletest prints the time it takes to run each test. To disable that, run the test program with the `--gtest_print_time=0` command line flag, or set the `GTEST_PRINT_TIME` environment variable to 0.

Comment: +1 this is almost what I'm looking for - if I could actually access the result per test as part of some validation, that would be perfect: eg `EXPECT_LT( TEST_RUNTIME, 1000)` for less than a thousand milliseconds...

Answer (score 4):

Some updates on this question (in 2016):

1. [Here](https://bruun.co/2012/02/07/easy-cpp-benchmarking) is a nice blog-post of Nick Brunn about his [Hayai](https://github.com/nickbruun/hayai) benchmarking framework. (2012)

   - It does not provide the possibility of specifying running time requirements.
   - It is very similar to Google Test. Syntax, etc.
   - It provides the benchmarking results to the user or a Continous Integration framework. Also have a look at [MojaveWastelander](https://github.com/MojaveWastelander/hayai)'s fork for active development and MSVC support.
2. Google published ['Benchmark'](https://github.com/google/benchmark) in [2014](https://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2014/01/introducing-benchmark.html). This provides similar behaviour then Hayai above. As far as I understand, defining requirements is not possible. Again, the syntax is inspired by GoogleTest.

   - There are even advanced features such as measuring complexity (big-O).
3. GoogleTest has this as an open feature on [Github](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/348). There is a rudimentary [implementation](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/348#issuecomment-235674063) but it is not part of GoogleTest yet.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just as simple as this?

```
const clock_t t0 = clock(); // or gettimeofday or whatever
int res = yourFunction();
const clock_t t1 = clock();
const double elapsedSec = (t1 - t0) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
EXPECT_EQ(EXPECTED, res);
EXPECT_GT(10.0, elapsedSec);
```

Here, you need to manually change `10.0` depending on your task.

Of course, you can go further by something like:

```
double prev = -1;
{
  ifstream ifs("/var/tmp/time_record.txt");
  ifs >> prev;
}
if (prev < 0) prev = DEFAULT_VALUE;
// ...
EXPECT_GT(2 * prev, elapsedSec);
{
  ofstream ofs("/var/tmp/time_record.txt");
  ofs << elapsedSec << endl;
}
```

But I wonder this additional complexity can really be justified.

Comment: Or, if possible, use the std::chrono libraries from C++11. The googletest library works fine when compiling for C++11 as well.